# How to override delete behavior in formset of admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

The scenario:

I have models like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    ...
```

In the admin I have something like this:

```
class AInlinde(admin.StackedInline):
    ...
    model = A
    ...

class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     ...
     inlines = [AInline]
     ...
```

Now I need to record in a log when a user deletes some model in the inline, but I can't follow the code, until now, I know `Badmin` have a method: `save_formset`, which is this:

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    """
    Given an inline formset save it to the database.
    """
    formset.save()
```

but I think that `formset` is generated through the method `modelformset_factory`, so I can't know when I can override the delete behavior of that formset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way for override how the formset saves or deletes the objects, is make a class that inherits from `BaseInlineFormSet` and override the methods `save` and `save_existing_objects`:

```
class NoDeleteFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def save(self, commit=True, request=None):
        """Saves model instances for every form, adding and changing instances
        as necessary, and returns the list of instances.
        """
        if not commit:
            self.saved_forms = []
            def save_m2m():
                for form in self.saved_forms:
                    form.save_m2m()
            self.save_m2m = save_m2m
        return self.save_existing_objects(commit) + self.save_new_objects(commit)

    def save_existing_objects(self, commit=True, request=None):
        self.changed_objects = []
        self.deleted_objects = []
        if not self.initial_forms:
            return []

        saved_instances = []
        for form in self.initial_forms:
            pk_name = self._pk_field.name
            raw_pk_value = form._raw_value(pk_name)

            # clean() for different types of PK fields can sometimes return
            # the model instance, and sometimes the PK. Handle either.
            pk_value = form.fields[pk_name].clean(raw_pk_value)
            pk_value = getattr(pk_value, 'pk', pk_value)

            obj = self._existing_object(pk_value)
            if self.can_delete and self._should_delete_form(form):
                self.deleted_objects.append(obj)
                obj.deleted_at = datetime.now()
                obj.save()

                # log there your user deleting the object!

                continue
            if form.has_changed():
                self.changed_objects.append((obj, form.changed_data))
                saved_instances.append(self.save_existing(form, obj, commit=commit))
                if not commit:
                    self.saved_forms.append(form)
        return saved_instances
```

Then construct a class than inherits from `StackedInline`:

```
class MetaInline(StackedInline):
    formset = NoDeleteFormset
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for soft deletes and logging deletes in 2017.
Nowadays in django 1.11 you can override **delete_existing** method

### For regular formsets

```
class SoftDeleteModelFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def delete_existing(self, obj, commit=True):
        """Deletes an existing model instance."""
        if commit:
            obj.deleted_at = datetime.datetime.now()
            obj.save()

            # log here
```

### For related models

```
class SoftDeleteInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def delete_existing(self, obj, commit=True):
        """Deletes an existing model instance."""
        if commit:
            obj.deleted_at = datetime.datetime.now()
            obj.save()

            # log here
```

And use modelformset_factory with new formset

```
product_formset = modelformset_factory(
    ...
    formset = SoftDeleteModelFormSet,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Works great but it's not documented... Are we sure it will stay as is?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to customize the default `ModelAdmin` delete behavior, just connect to the [`django.db.models.signals.post_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_delete) and get a hook on the model after it's deleted and log it there.

Comment: I need customize that behavior, because I need change it in the admin, not in all my project.